# Windows Store apps BitmapImage caching from Stream

Tags: c#, image, windows-store-apps

I'm creating a DependencyObject to use as an image downloader, the behavior I'm expecting is that once it has downloaded the application caches the image, this behavior is normal when you bind an Image control to a BitmapImage created from an Uri or directly binding the Uri itself. However that's not the case when using a Stream, at least in my case, this is my code:

```
    if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( ImageEx.GetImage( this ) ) ) return;

        ImageBitmap = new BitmapImage( new Uri( String.Concat( "ms-appx:///", ImageEx.GetLoadingImage( this ) ) ) );
        //ImageBitmap = new BitmapImage( new Uri( ImageEx.GetImage( this ), UriKind.Absolute ) );
        //return;

        try {
            var ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync( ImageEx.GetImage( this ) );

            await stream.CopyToAsync( memoryStream );
            var output = ras.GetOutputStreamAt( 0 );
            var dw = new DataWriter( output );
            var task = new Task( () => dw.WriteBytes( memoryStream.ToArray() ) );
            task.Start();

            await task;
            await dw.StoreAsync();

            await output.FlushAsync();

            ImageBitmap = new BitmapImage();
            await ImageBitmap.SetSourceAsync( ras);             


        } catch ( Exception ex ) {

    }
```

so when I go forth and back in the application, everytime the Image reloads instead of caching the BitmapImage like when it's created with the Uri or binding the Image control directly to an Uri. How can I prevent the BitmapImage from loading again?

Thanks

Comment: Create a manual cache, likely through your IOC, which is just a dictionary of keys mapped to the byte arrays so you don't have to download it each time (and you get to keep it memory). Then, before doing your try/catch, check to see if you have a cache hit. If you do, set the source of the bitmap to that. If not, go grab it from the disk. You can add some extra functionality like limiting the amount of images cached at a time. I think there are some libraries on CodePlex that can help with this as well.

Comment: Seems like the way to go, thanks, I'm still wondering why the built in cache works fine in Windows Phone using a similar approach for the loader.

Comment: The way Windows Phone caches the pages may have something to do with it, in that it caches the entire control instead of just the 'contents' for the control.